# Range of IDs via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I understand that I can use `People.first(100)` to retrieve the first 100 records, same goes for `People.last(100)`.

What I don`t know, is how do I **retrieve all objects in the range of 200-400**, when the total number is lets say a 1000 records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `limit` and `offset` - read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) for more info.

Example:

```
People.limit(200).offset(200)
```

The above code takes 200 records starting from 201st record - that means it would be records 201-400.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not return values within a range, it will return 200 records starting at the 201st record.  So say you've deleted 50 records with ids between 200 and 400, you're going to get 200 records but your records could have an id of anywhere between 200 and 450.  Does that make sense?  So the limit-offset method ensures you get 200 records, but if you're looking for a range of ids(or some other field) you would use the where method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching on a specific field, your title suggests you're searching on id?

```
People.where('id BETWEEN ? AND ?', 200, 400)
```

or...

```
People.where(id: 200..400)
```

If you're not searching on a particular field, you would want to use Big_Bird's limit and offset methods.